# Google Music causes Windows Notification sound for each new track

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, notifications

Chrome 68 introduced notifications in the Windows built-in notification system. Google Play Music shows a notification for each track as it begins which causes the system to play the sound for a new notification, interrupting the music. Is there a way to disable the notification sounds just for Google Play Music? I want the notifications from all the other programs and even most other websites running in Chrome (if it is possible to keep).

Comment: Any notification sender can be enabled/disabled independently: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028678/windows-10-change-notification-settings